# Json + C# web services - decimal numbers being save incorrectly

Tags: c#, jquery, json, web-services

I'm creating an application using jQuery and consuming C# web services through json, everything works great, however I'm trying to insert records in a database, and everytime that I try to insert a decimal number (ie. 2.1) I get an error "500 undefined" and if I change the dot for comma (2,1) the number is saved as "21". This is the jquery code:

```
        //Function to add a report line
        function addReportLine()
        {
            var productVal  = $("#productCode").val();
            var nameVal     = $("#productName").val();
            var unitVal     = $("#unitPrice").val(); //This is the decimal number
            var qtyVal      = $("#qty").val();  
            var totalVal    = $("#totalPrice").val();                           
            var whVal       = "";                       
            var userVal     = $("#username").val();         

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                url: "http://IpAddress/Service1.svc/addReportLine",
                data: JSON.stringify({ productId: productVal, productName: nameVal, warehouse: whVal, unitPrice: unitVal, totalPrice: totalVal, qty: qtyVal, currentUser: userVal }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data){
                    populateReportGrid();                                                       
                },
                error: function(result){
                    alert(result.status + ' ' + result.StatusText); 
                }
            });                 
        }
```

This is the code that is being used from the web service:

```
    //Add line to report
    public void addReportLine(string productId, string productName, string warehouse, string unitPrice, string totalPrice, string qty, string currentUser)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = DbManagement.getConnection();
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = null;
            SqlCommand command = null; ;
            SqlCommand insertCommand, updateCommand;
            Boolean isUpdate = false;

            //Insert
            insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO isProductReport(productId, productName, unitPrice, qty, userId, warehouseId, totalPrice) " +
                                           "VALUES('" + productId + "', " +
                                                  "'" + productName + "', " +
                                                   "" + Double.Parse(unitValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ", " +
                                                   "" + Convert.ToInt32(qtyValue) + ", " +
                                                  "'" + currentUser + "', " +
                                                  "'" + warehouse + "', " +
                                                   "" + Double.Parse(totalValue, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ")", connection);
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Here's the problem: **The server where the DB is, have configured a "," (comma) as decimal separator, and "." (dot) as thousands separator**, so I initially ended up using **CultureInfo.InvariantCulture** in another application (which does not use json) to save it correctly and it worked. If I run the web service in my computer locally, the data is saved correctly, but if I call the web service hosted in the server, then I get the errors.

If I leave the number with the "." I get error "500 undefined", but if I change it to "," (for testing purposes) it saves the number without any separator. I'd like to know what can I do to save it properly in the database, I would appreciate your help, thanks!

**EDIT**

I have to thank **Chuck Conway**, not for the direct answer, but for telling me about the "network" tab in Firefox, which allowed me to see the exact error, after enabling "debug" in the web.config. It turns out that, since the configuration in the server was replacing dots in decimals for commas, the insert query was recognizing all the decimals as separate parameters (for example 2.21 was being recognized as '2','21') so the number of parameters did not match the number of fields specified in the query. I ended up inserting the values without any conversion to Double and SQL server did the trick.

THANKS A LOT!! (I'd like to mark any of your comments as the answer, but it seems like comments cannot be marked as answers.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: The only error that I'm getting is "500 undefined", if there's a way to get a more detailed error, just let me know, and I'll post it here.

Comment: A couple suggestions: The parameters should be the type you pass to the SqlCommand. The string concatenation opens this code up for sql injection. Lastly if you plan to use a try/catch over a using statement close the connection and the command in the finally clause.

Comment: Yeah, it depends. Can you look at fiddler or the network tool in Chrome or FireFox? Sometime the server returns the stack with the response. It just depends on how your server is set up. If it's not showing the stacktrace it can be changed in the web.config.

Comment: what should I specify in the web.config to get a better response?

Comment: Here's how to enable debugging. Ignore the targetFramework. That's not needed. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/12/14/enable-debugging-in-web-config-vstipproj0026.aspx